# Error while publishing a vs project to Azure "An item with the same key has already been added"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, azure-mobile-services

Recently I have started getting this error while publishing, it published twice, and then suddenly this error starts appearing, no idea what this is all about

[image]

Comment: Please provide logs from the output window. See if any changes happened on the publish profile. If you have version control, try to re-publish the last version you had successfully published and then trace the changes. Not enough information otherwise for anyone to help.

Comment: thanks. Output window is completely blank, going back to previous version also doesn't work. I know that is not enough information, but I couldn't fnd any relevant information, I deleted the .user file, still the same issue

Comment: Have you tried to backup & delete your .pubxml file and republish your application? Would you please provide your publish profile and erase the sensitive information?

Comment: I have the same problem on VS 2017 RC.  The only way around it is to delete the Publish profiles in the Properties directory and also remove the references from the web project's .csproj file.  However, the fix usually only lasts 2-3 publishes, then the problem reemerges and I have to reset again.  Very annoying.

Comment: Thanks, deleting publish profile worked fine,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

delete the Publish profiles in the Properties directory

Comment: Yeah while this might work - why is this happening? And why am I supposed to delete this profile and then manually recreate the publishing data afterwards? This is not a solution, only a workaround...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that is fixed by an release.

Every time you publish a new MSDeployParameterValue appears in my Web Deploy.pubxml file that create a duplicate.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/9339/duplicate-msdeployparametervalue.html

Here to update Visual Studio 2017:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-visual-studio